# Indian Passport correction + US Visa

Tags: passports, india, indian-citizens

I am an Indian with an Indian Passport. I am also currently in the US with a student - F1 visa.

I have a query about the way my name is printed in my passport. In the passport, I don't have any name in the "first name/ given name" section.

Both my first name and last name have been entered in my "last name section".

So my name according to the passport (fn/ln) is ______/Aditya Narasimhamurthy.

I want "Aditya" to be in my first name. I also want to split my last name into "Narasimha" and "Murthy", instead of being just 1 word.

I also want "Narasimha" to be my Initial.

So the final result I'm looking for is:

(fn) Aditya

(mi) Narasimha

(surname) Murthy

I just need to know if all this can be achieved together in just 1 application or if I need to submit different applications? Also how much would it cost.

And finally, would it affect my VISA, as the visa has same name formatting I have in my passport now.

Comment: An initial is a single letter.  What you want (I think) is for Narasimha to be your middle *name,* which would mean that your middle initial is *N.*  This is how it works according to US usage, at any rate.  Collectively, first and middle names are known as *given names* (among other terms), and, IIRC, they are listed together in most passports.  Finally, *visa* is not an acronym, and should not be written in all caps.  Unfortunately, however, I do not know the answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For a correction in your name, it is possible to contact the Indian embassy nearest to you in the US. You can call them directly and ask your query.

You would ideally need to apply for a reissue of your passport for name correction. This requires you to fill out a new application form, send a copy of your residence permit etc., which can be obtained from the consulate's website.

[Here](http://www.blsindia-usa.com/passport/apply_postal.php) is a link which gives detailed information on the procedure for applying for a reissue of passport.

After you apply, if there is anything that is missing from your application, the authorities usually contact you by phone and might ask you to send the missing documents.